# FileChooser plugin for ionic in ios platform

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, filechooser

I am working in a project using ionic, in which I have a button which lets the user open the file explorer of their device and pick pdf files which would be uploaded. 
I have successfully implemented this feature for android using a Filechooser plugin from : https://github.com/tigoe/BeginningNFC/tree/master/FileSender/plugins/com.megster.cordova.FileChooser
However this plugin is not working for ios platform. On searching I have found only one plugin for ios, i.e.
https://github.com/jcesarmobile/FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin
However, it support only ios 8 or above. Can anyone help me with this?? 
Is there any other plugin, or any other ways that I do not know??